# postgresql timeclock entry with no matching pair

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE timeclock(
     employeeid INT
     , logdate DATE
     , logtime TIME
     , timetype VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, '2013-01-01', '07:00', 'I'),
(1, '2013-01-01', '07:01', 'I'),
(1, '2013-01-01', '16:00', 'O'),
(1, '2013-01-01', '16:01', 'O'),
(2, '2013-01-01', '07:00', 'I'),
(2, '2013-01-01', '16:00', 'O'),
(1, '2013-01-02', '07:00', 'I'),
(1, '2013-01-02', '16:30', 'O'),
(2, '2013-01-02', '06:30', 'I'),
(2, '2013-01-02', '15:30', 'O'),
(2, '2013-01-02', '16:30', 'I'),
(2, '2013-01-02', '23:30', 'O'),
(3, '2013-01-01', '06:30', 'I'),
(3, '2013-01-02', '16:30', 'O'),
(4, '2013-01-01', '20:30', 'I'),
(4, '2013-01-02', '05:30', 'O'),
(5, '2013-01-01', '20:30', 'O'),
(5, '2013-01-02', '05:30', 'I');
```

I need to get the the time IN and OUT of each employee, disregarding duplicate entries
and identifying orphan entries (without a matching IN or OUT) so that I can put it in a separate list for notification of missing entries.

so far I have this sql that I modified which I got from Peter Larsson's Island and Gaps solution ([link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/solving-complex-t-sql-problems,-step-by-step/)) :

```
WITH cteIslands ( employeeid, timetype, logdate, logtime, grp) 
       AS ( SELECT employeeid, timetype, logdate, logtime, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() 
                    OVER ( ORDER BY employeeid, logdate, logtime ) 
                 - ROW_NUMBER() 
                    OVER ( ORDER BY timetype, employeeid, 
                                    logdate, logtime ) AS grp 
             FROM timeclock
           ),
      cteGrouped ( employeeid, timetype, logdate, logtime ) 
      AS ( SELECT employeeid, MIN(timetype), logdate, 
                  CASE WHEN MIN(timetype) = 'I' 
                       THEN MIN(logtime) 
                       ELSE MAX(logtime) 
                  END AS logtime
           FROM cteIslands 
           GROUP BY employeeid, logdate, grp 
         ) 
select * from cteIslands
order by employeeid, logdate, logtime
```

The above works fine in satisfying the removal of duplicate entries but now I cant seem to get the orphan entries.  I think LEAD or LAG can be used on this but I am new with postgresql.  I hope someone here can help me on this.

Edit:
I somehow need to add a new field that I can use so that I know which records are orphaned.
somethine like the table below:

```
EMPID   TYPE    LOGDATE     LOGTIME    ORPHAN_FLAG
1          I    2013-01-01  07:00:00    0
1          O    2013-01-01  16:01:00    0
1          I    2013-01-02  07:00:00    0
1          O    2013-01-02  16:30:00    0
2          I    2013-01-01  07:00:00    0
2          O    2013-01-01  16:00:00    0
2          I    2013-01-02  06:30:00    0
2          O    2013-01-02  15:30:00    0
2          I    2013-01-02  16:30:00    0
2          O    2013-01-02  23:30:00    0
3          I    2013-01-01  06:30:00    0
3          O    2013-01-02  16:30:00    0
4          I    2013-01-01  20:30:00    0
4          O    2013-01-02  05:30:00    0
5          O    2013-01-01  20:30:00    1   <--- NO MATCHING IN
5          I    2013-01-02  05:30:00    1   <--- NO MATCHING OUT
```

Comment: Do you want min intime and max outime for given day?

Comment: The code I posted already handles the min time and max time for the day.  What I need now is to identify the orphan records (without IN or OUT match).  I think I need a new computed field which would flag the record as orphaned or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you should rethink your design a little bit.  It makes little sense to record a clock-out entry without having clocked in, and you can use things like partial indexes to ensure that clocked in entries are easy to look up when they don't have a clock out entry.

So I would start by considering moving your storage tables to something like:

```
CREATE TABLE timeclock(
     employeeid INT
     , logdate DATE
     , logintime TIME
     , logouttime time
     , timetype VARCHAR(1)
);
```

The bad news is that if you can't do that, your orphanned report will be  quite difficult to make perform well because you are doing a self join where you hope every row in a large table will have a corresponding other entry.   This is going to require, at best, two sequential scans on the table and at worst a sequential scan with a nested loop index scan (assuming proper indexes, the alternative, a nested loop sequential scan would be even worse).

Handling this where you have rollover between dates (clock in at 11pm, clock out at 2am) will make this problem very hard to avoid.

Now since you have your CTE's working fine except for orphanned records, my recommendation is that union with another query on the same table looking for those which are not found properly in your current query.